# Draw Two Graph in Different Positions in NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I Want to Draw two Different Graph in Different Positions Using Networkx, E.g. G1 on left side of canvas and G2 on the right side ,But I dont know how to do it, here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import socialModels as sm
G1 = sm.nearestNeighbor_mod(256, 0.6, 1)
G2 = sm.nearestNeighbor_mod(256, 0.6, 1)
elarge1 =[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G1.edges(data=True)]
elarge2 =[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G2.edges(data=True)]

pos1=nx.spring_layout(G1)
pos2=nx.spring_layout(G2)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G1,pos1,node_size=30,node_color='b')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G1,pos1,edgelist=elarge1,width=1,style='solid')


nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G2,pos2,node_size=50)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G2,pos2,edgelist=elarge2,width=1)


nx.write_graphml(G1,'test.graphml')
plt.show() # display
plt.draw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about shifting the positions in pos2 with the desired value?

A working example would be

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G1 = nx.balanced_tree(2,1)
G2 = nx.balanced_tree(2,2)


elarge1 =[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G1.edges(data=True)]
elarge2 =[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G2.edges(data=True)]


pos1=nx.spring_layout(G1)
pos2=nx.spring_layout(G2)


for k,v in pos2.items():
    # Shift the x values of every node by 10 to the right
    v[0] = v[0] +10

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G1,pos1,node_size=30,node_color='b')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G1,pos1,edgelist=elarge1,width=1,style='solid')


nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G2,pos2,node_size=50)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G2,pos2,edgelist=elarge2,width=1)

plt.show() # display
plt.draw()
```

You can think about a good value of shifting by evaluating the positions in Graph one or two and compute your desired shift...

Comment: Dear Stefan, do you know any way to establish random edge between two random graph in networkx

Comment: That's a good question. An obvious way would be to combine the two graphs and then draw any random edge between them, but you'll loose the ability to layout them separately. Depending on your Use Case (e.g. If you don't need to have the graphs separated) a nx.MultiGraph could also be a solution for your problem

Comment: Thank you for your response but i want to have a separate layout of two graph , left graph represent a community and right graph represent another community  and there is random edge(relationship) between two graph(community) , any other solution is appreciated,

Comment: You should then think about a wrapper class where you can add multiple independent graphs layout them and then combine them into 1 graph by shifting the node id's. After doing that you are able to draw any edge between them, but you need also take care on unique id's of your nodes...
I did something similar by just shifting the id's of the second graph with the amount of nodes of the first graph.

Comment: Many thanks, How is it possible to change the position of half of edges in same graph?

Comment: I didn't changed the position of edges at all but the positions of the nodes. Since doing that you also change the (from and to) position of the edge...